# Apply policy management column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, policy-based-management

I want to apply a specific rule when somebody create new column in SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.

For example:

**NR**_NameColumn = **int**

**IS**_Deleted = **bit**

**DT**_update = **Date**

**ID**_User = **int**

and etc...

How can I apply it?

Comment: Version, platform etc may help others in answering your question.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2016 SP1 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Most of that can be accomplished with something such as [DDL triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver16), but that's  heavy handed. Ideally anything such as this would be committed and gone through a code review or have automated tooling search and blame the committer.

There is Policy Based Management but in this case it's a fancy GUI which would end up making DDL triggers behind the scenes, so that's an option if you want a GUI for it.